# NGINX doesn't pass Content-Type when used as Reverse Proxy

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Trying to get NGINX to provide reverse proxy functionality and it seems the "Content-Type" header isn't returned to the user correctly.

```
 server {
                listen 80;
                server_name <url>;
                gzip off;
                gzip_proxied off;
                location / {
                        resolver 8.8.8.8;
                        proxy_pass https://<serverurl>/;
                        proxy_set_header Host <hostname>;
                        proxy_pass_header "Content-Type";
                        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding identity;
                        proxy_ssl_name <hostname>;
                        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
                        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
                }
        }
```

All the objects are returned but everything has "text/html" content-type being set which breaks the site.

Any ideas why NGINX omits/overwrites the Content-Type